# Evaluating $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {2^k}{5^{2^k}+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, contest-math

So my teacher shared this problem with us and said everyone needs to try this, he teaches us Olympiad Math so I am assuming this wouldn't require analysis or calculus. This is the question, I have been on this from 2 days but it seems impossible. How to solve this?

> Sum of the following expression:
>
> $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {2^k}{5^{2^k}+1}$$